# Why the need to say "Haufen Langweiler" instead of "Haufen Langweilern"?

Tags: declension

> Was treibt eine solch hübsche junge Dame dazu, mit einem Haufen **Langweiler** herumzuhängen?

Considering that the preposition *mit* should be followed by a dative form, I would be tempted to say *Langweilern* (Plural Dative) instead. I wonder why *Langweiler* is the correct word here? I suppose it is not the dative form.

Comment: Ein Haufen (lit. _a pile_) describes a quantity. As a result, genitive plural is correct. There's more than one way to do it, though: http://canoo.net/blog/2011/06/15/eine-menge-schwarze-schafe/

Comment: see http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35221/what-is-the-construction-in-this-headline-millionen-syrische-kinder-leiden-unt/35222#35222

Comment: You would use the plural with _ein Haufen **von** Langweilern_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is "Haufen" (=pile) that is in dative, not the content of the pile. The content of something can be expressed with a genitive construction, as in this case.

Comment: Hi. I wonder if the same can be said for "ein Stück **Luxus**"?

Comment: It is hard to say whether it is genitive or nominative, though.

Comment: @Alone-zee no, in "ein Stück Luxus" there isn't any contain in "ein Stück". It is only the amount, just as it would be with "ein bisschen"